# Page refreshes unless I put js file inside the template itself

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a js file that handle "likes" on my website. The like section for each post is in a separate HTML file. Unless I put the js file in the template itself (rather than the base HTML file) the page refreshes after second click.

This is my AJAX function:

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $('.buzz-like-form').on("click", ".buzz-like-btn", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        var btn = $(this)
        var tk = $(this).attr("data-token");
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: $(this).attr("data-url"),
            dataType: 'json',
            data: $(this).closest("form").serialize(),
            success: function (data){
                $(btn).closest(".buzz-likes-container").html(data.buzz);
            },
            error: function(rs, e){
                console.log(rs.responeText);
            },
        });
    });
})
```

This is my template:

```
{% load static %}
<form class="buzz-like-form"  method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% if request.user in buzz.likes.all %}
    <button class="btn no-border p-0 mr-4  btn-md  buzz-like-btn button-hide-outline" type="submit" 
        data-url="{% url 'home:buzz-like' guid_url=buzz.guid_url  status='rmvlike' %}">
        <i class="fas  mr-2 fa-thumbs-up" style="color:  rgb(43, 98, 153);"></i><span class="text-muted small">{{ buzz.likes.count }}</span></button> 

    <button class="btn no-border p-0 mr-4 btn-md buzz-like-btn button-hide-outline" type="submit" 
         data-url="{% url 'home:buzz-like' guid_url=buzz.guid_url  status='udislike' %}">
        <i class="fas mr-2 fa-thumbs-down"  style="color:  rgb(185, 186, 187);"></i><span class="text-muted small">{{ buzz.dislikes.count }}</span></button> 

    {% elif request.user in buzz.dislikes.all %}

    <button class="btn no-border p-0 mr-4 btn-md  buzz-like-btn  button-hide-outline" type="submit" 
        data-url="{% url 'home:buzz-like' guid_url=buzz.guid_url  status='ulike' %}">
        <i class="fas mr-2 fa-thumbs-up" style="color:  rgb(185, 186, 187);"></i><span class="text-muted small">{{ buzz.likes.count }}</span></button>

    <button class="btn no-border p-0 mr-4 btn-md  buzz-like-btn  button-hide-outline" type="submit" 
     data-url="{% url 'home:buzz-like' guid_url=buzz.guid_url  status='rmvdislike' %}">
    <i class="fas mr-2 fa-thumbs-down" style="color:  rgb(240, 78, 78);"></i><span class="text-muted small">{{ buzz.dislikes.count }}</span></button>

    {% else %}

    <button class="btn no-border p-0 mr-4  btn-md  buzz-like-btn  button-hide-outline" type="submit" 
        data-url="{% url 'home:buzz-like' guid_url=buzz.guid_url  status='like' %}">
        <i class="fas mr-2 fa-thumbs-up"  style="color:  rgb(185, 186, 187);"></i><span class="text-muted small">{{ buzz.likes.count }}</span></button>

    <button class="btn no-border p-0 mr-4 btn-md buzz-like-btn  button-hide-outline" type="submit" 
       data-url="{% url 'home:buzz-like' guid_url=buzz.guid_url  status='dislike' %}">
        <i class="fas mr-2 fa-thumbs-down"  style="color:  rgb(185, 186, 187);"></i><span class="text-muted small">{{ buzz.dislikes.count }}</span></button>

    {% endif %}
</form>
```

Unless I add the script to the end of the base template the after first AJAX call if I click on a like button it will refresh the page and I can only get it to work if I put it inside the "like" template. Why is this happening?

This is where it is supposed to be refreshed:

```
<div class="mr-1 buzz-likes-container">
    {% include 'home/buzz/buzz_like.html' %}
</div>
```

This part is where the form is and should be refreshed.

I was wondering if this will resolve the issue:

```
<div class="mr-1 buzz-likes-container">
    <div>
        {% include 'home/buzz/buzz_like.html' %}
    </div>
</div>
```

And use in the `success` function? (I tried and it is not working)

```
 $(btn).closest(".buzz-likes-container div").html(data.buzz);
```

Comment: Buttons of type `submit` are causing refreshs. They are used for e.g. posting a form. Remove the types, so the default `type="button"` is used.

Comment: @Paul `e.preventDefault();` as OP is using should resolve that issue

Comment: Not clear where `.buzz-likes-container` is in the html. My guess is you are replacing the whole form when you do `$(btn).closest(".buzz-likes-container").html(data.buzz);` . If that is the case you need to move the delegation higher to an element that exists all the time...like `$(document).on("click", ".buzz-like-btn"....`

Comment: @charlietfl I added the part which is being refreshed. Inside the `buzz-likes-container` but I didn't quite understand what you meant by moving the delegation higher?

Comment: @Paul `type="button"` is unfortunately not the default. When part of a form, the default is `type="submit"`